# Linux command to view history to two or more open terminals?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

If i have open three terminals which Linux terminal command will help me to view three terminals history in one terminal. And i have followed the Linux command `history` and `history | more`. Hence i not get the desired output.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming

Comment: I guess (but don't know since the wording is unclear) that OP wants to get the history of the shells running in three different terminal windows.  This would mean ① get the history of the three shells, ② merge them somehow, and ③ display the merge result.  While there are aspects stil unclear, this sounds a lot like a programming question to me.

Comment: @reenadevi, please clarify your question.  I phrased an assumption in my comment above, but I'm less than sure that is what you want.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/94439/can-i-create-a-separate-bash-history-file-for-each-terminal-profile  To view the files simultainously use commend "multitail file1 file2..."

Comment: See also https://www.baeldung.com/linux/preserve-history-multiple-windows on how to program this into your `.bashrc` file

Answer (score 4):

Bash persists command history in `~/.bash_history` by default. Usually, the file is written only when Bash exits, so there is no way to access other sessions' history.

However, the built-in `history` command has a few switches to control history persistence:

- `-w` writes the session's history and replaces the file
- `-r` reads history from file and replaces the session's history
- `-a` appends only lines added in the session
- `-n` reads the file and adds entries that are not in the current session
- `-c` clears the session's history

If you don't mind the I/O overhead, a combination of these can be executed after every command by adding it to `$PROMPT_COMMAND` in your `~/.bashrc`:

- I have first tested the more obvious way of reading new entries from other sessions, then persisting all:

  ```
  PROMPT_COMMAND='history -n ; history -w'
  ```

  While this basically does work, single entries get lost sometimes and I am not sure about the reason.
- The following solution borrowed from [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows) works better (it will append one item, clear the session history, then re-read it):

  ```
  PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a ; history -c ;  history -r'
  ```

Comment: The switches of the command `history` are visible via `history --help` or `help history`. `man history` shows other information on the command arguments.